# Using PdfBox, how do I retrieve contents of PDDocument as a byte array?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am currently using PdfBox as the driver for a pdf-file editor application.
I need the contents of the PdfBox representation of a pdf file (PDDocument) as a byte array.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: did you ever find out? I'd like to know too...

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I hope it's not too late...

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
document.save(byteArrayOutputStream);
document.close();
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
```

And voila! You've got both input streams!

Comment: sorry for the late response.

Comment: The answer is correct, at least for the version of PDFBox that I checked (1.8.4)

Comment: Working fine in org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:2.0.4

Comment: Works also fine in the latest available version (2.0.23)

Comment: You saved me. The PDFMergeUtility is an effin' mess in the 2.0.* and was unable to merge PDDocuments with Type0 Fonts. So I saved both files in a stream and then could merge them later as inputstreams.

Comment: @ak.leimrey - Do you mind sharing the bits you used for merging?  Thanks