# Java PDFBox, how to get File object from PDDocument

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to retrieve a `File` or `InputStream` instance from `PDDocument` without saving a `PDDocument` to the file system.

```
 PDDocument doc= new PDDocument(); 
 ...     
 doc.save("D:\\document.pdf"); 
 File f= new File("D:\\document.pdf");
```

Is there any method in `PDFBox` which returns `File` or `InputStream` from an existing `PDDocument`?

Answer (score 9):

I solved it:

```
PDDocument doc=new PDDocument();        
PDStream ps=new PDStream(doc);
InputStream is=ps.createInputStream();
```

Comment: This "solution" does not make any sense. I doubt any of the up-voters has actually tested it, nor do they seem to know PDFBox. E.g. the JavaDocs of the `public PDStream(PDDocument document)` constructor describe the `document` parameter as *The document that the stream will be part of.* So `ps=new PDStream(doc)` merely creates a new (empty) PDF stream *inside* the document, *not* a stream *containing* the document.

Comment: Maybe it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593116/using-pdfbox-how-do-i-retrieve-contents-of-pddocument-as-a-byte-array/17656461#17656461

Answer (score 5):

I solve it in this way ( It's creating a file but in temporary-file directory ):

```
final PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
final File file = File.createTempFile(filename, ".pdf");
document.save(file);
```

and if you need

```
document.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you first create the outputstream

```
PDDocument doc= new PDDocument(); 
File f= new File("D:\\document.pdf");
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(f);  
doc.save(fOut);
```

Take a look at this
http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html#save(java.io.OutputStream)

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to create a file on my file system, I want to put this pdf file directly in Alfresco repository...do you have any idea how can I do this?

Comment: @MilosGavrilov and what protocol does alfresco support to do this transfer? Because as soon as you get an outputstream to write to you are good to go

Comment: this does not answer the question as it gets the stream from a file on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to retrieve a `File` or `InputStream` instance from `PDDocument` without saving a `PDDocument` to the file system.
>
> [...]
>
> Is there any method in `PDFBox` which returns `File` or `InputStream` from an existing `PDDocument`?

Obviously PDFBox cannot return a meaningful `File` object *without saving a `PDDocument` to the file system*.

It does not offer a method providing an `InputStream` directly either but it is easy to write code around it that does. e.g.:

```
InputStream docInputStream = null;

try (   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PDDocument doc = new PDDocument()   )
{
    [...]
    doc.save(baos);
    docInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**I'm trying the same thing I discovered this class

> Class PageExtractor

you can try it like this**